# How to rectify class not found in psy shell in laravel tinker?

Tags: laravel, tinker

I am very new to the laravel tinker part, I have one model based on that model I am trying to update some column value but it's throwing an error please help me to resolve the issue.

```
User::update(["status"=>"active"])->where ('id',1);
```

Error I am getting is

`PHP FATAL error: class 'User' not found in psy shell code on line1`

Comment: Probably the issue is related to your User model class, and it's because you are calling a "plans" class inside your User.php file without a correct "use" statement or incorrect namespace inside plans file, can you show us your User.php file?

Comment: what version of Laravel? ... majority of classes in your project are namespaced not in the root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `User::update(["status"=>"active"])->where ('id',1)->first();`
or better still:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->update(["status"=>"active"]);
```

Where 'plans' comes from must be a mistake in your User model. Did you add `private $with(['plans']);` or something similar in the model? Maybe you should post your `User.php` model in the question.

Comment: This is an improvement to the code, but has nothing to do with the error in question...

Comment: Thanks @BrianThompson. I have added information to my answer. It's probably due to a model error.